# Favicon not displaying on Prod - Create React App

Tags: reactjs, favicon

As the title suggests, in my React project, my favicon is displaying fine on my local machine, but not in production.

I've tried both using an absolute link for the file path, as well as:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

I've also tried adding the .ico file in the images folder within my src folder, but still no luck!

Does anyone know what I might be missing?
Cheers

Comment: Clear your cache. Try in incognito.

Comment: Yeah I thought it could be caching, but it doesnt seem to be, as I've tried both those suggestions.

Comment: Clearing the cache works.